# Difference between JWE encryption algorithm RSAES-PKCS1-v1_5 and RSAES OAEP

Tags: rsa, jwe

In the specifications of JWE (RFC7516) they specify the values for (asymmetrically) encrypting the symmetric key. In RFC7518 in [section 4.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7518#page-22) they list the options, of which two are relevant for my case

```
alg = RSA1_5 (RSAES-PKCS1-v1_5)
```

or

```
alg = RSA-OAEP (RSAES OAEP using default parameters)
```

Both use RSA-keys of size 2048 at least. They come with a different recommendation (Recommended- and Recommended+, respectively). What are the main differences between these two algorithms for JWE, and is there a specific use of JWE that would prefer the one above the other?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How much safer is RSA-OAEP compared to RSA with PKCS#1 v1.5 padding?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/47437/18298)

Comment: I had not seen the question, however to me the question (or the answer) do not make clear what the exact difference is, and what would be preferred in this use case (or other use cases)