# How should I address message size limits in RSA encryption?

Tags: rsa, prime-numbers, number-theory

I am making an **end-to-end encryption software** program in Java using **RSA**. I am using BigIntegers and its number theory methods. (I know this is a very slow approach, but I just want to learn to the concept of encryption through this). I have a lot of questions, feel free to only answer as many as you'd like.
I have most of the encryption done already but I have questions about the size limitations of RSA and its technical details.
Say I generate primes p and q for my RSA which are of bit length 256 and 257. 
According to my intuition on the number theory behind it (using modulus) and a lot of test cases, **I should be able to safely encrypt and decrypt any number with bit lengths L < 513 (256+257) without losing information. Is this correct** and will work 100% of the time? Also if L happens to be a **5-bit number**, its **encrypted version will still be around ~512 bits long**?

I want to abstract my BigInteger (Java class) encryption to encrypting any byte[] of data. My plan is to split the byte[] into 512-bit (64-byte) chunks and encrypt those chunks by converting them to a BigInteger and then encrypting them. Is this a good idea? How is it done in industry?

Should I make the bit length of p and q smaller/larger and make the encryption chunks size smaller/larger to optimize performance?

Also, after I encrypt a number, the encrypted version ranges anywhere between 0 and 512 bits. How should I added padding to this byte[], in order to keep them of uniform size, for easy decrypting? Should I just add 0's to the most significant bit side and pad until it is always 512 bits?

Thank you so much for the help in advance!

Comment: RSA should not be used for encryption, even so, you should use it with proper padding. Otherwise, you are open to many attacks. See [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/70904/18298) or search for RSA-OAEP. If you want to use RSA, you should use it as key exchange and better use Diffie-Hellman Key exchange over Elliptic Curves.

Comment: In addition, 512 bit RSA keys are far too small nowadays; they should be at least 2048 bits...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I should be able to safely encrypt and decrypt any number with bit lengths L < 513 (256+257) without losing information. Is this correct[?]

No.  **The RSA operation $x \mapsto x^e \bmod n$ is unfit to ‘encrypt’ even short messages directly.**

Here is what you should do:

- Pick a hash function $H$ up front, like SHA-256 or SHAKE128, and bake it into your program.  (Don't let users pick it—users have even less of an idea of what's up.)
- Pick a **symmetric-key authenticated cipher** up front, like AES-GCM or NaCl crypto_secretbox_xsalsa20poly1305, and bake it into your program.  (Again, don't let users pick it.)
- To encrypt a message $m$, which is a bit string of *arbitrary length*, for public key $n$:

  1. Choose an integer $x$ with $0 \leq x < n$ uniformly at random.
  2. Compute $y = x^3 \bmod n$.
  3. Compute $k = H(x)$, where $x$ is encoded as a bit or octet string in some standard way, *e.g.* little-endian.
  4. Encrypt $m$ using your authenticated cipher under the key $k$, giving a ciphertext $c$.
  5. Send $y$ and $c$.  $y$ is called the *encapsulation* of the key $k$.
- To decrypt a ciphertext $c$ with key encapsulation $y$:

  1. Solve $y \equiv x^3 \pmod n$ for $x$.  (*E.g.*, compute $x = y^d \bmod n$ where $d$ solves $e d \equiv 1 \pmod{\phi(n)}$, or compute $x_p = y^{d_p} \bmod p$ and $x_q = y^{d_q} \bmod q$, and then combine using the Chinese remainder theorem, *etc.*)
  2. Compute $k = H(x)$.
  3. Decrypt $c$ using your authenticated cipher under the key $k$.

     - **If decryption fails, drop it all on the floor and stop here.**  (If you skip this step, you are setting yourself up for [efail](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/59241)ure.)
     - Otherwise, it returns a message $m$, which is the plaintext message you return in the end.

This system—generating a symmetric key $k = H(x)$ for uniform random $x$ and concealing it as $x^3 \bmod n$—is called **RSA-KEM**, and it is an example of a **public-key key encapsulation mechanism**, which can be generically composed with an authenticated cipher to get public-key (anonymous) encryption.

> Also if L happens to be a 5-bit number, its encrypted version will still be around ~512 bits long?

With the system above, the ciphertext overhead is 128 bits for the authenticated cipher (or more, if it's a particularly inefficient authenticated cipher), plus the size of your modulus $n$, no matter how long the message is.

**You should not use 512-bit moduli.  They have been breakable in practice by the public for decades.  You should use at least 2048-bit moduli.**  [More details.](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/1982)

Alternatively: Just use NaCl crypto_box, or libsodium crypto_box_seal.  Faster, smaller, safer than RSA!